# ¿Cargar autcompletado de easycomplete desde la base de datos?

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Estoy intentando llenar el autocompletado de easyautocomplete con información de la base de datos.

```
<div class="contenedor">

    <center><label for="" class="titulo">Cambio de cédulas de consumos</label></center>

    <label for="cc_tecnico">Cambiar cédula instaldor</label>
    <input type="radio" id="cc_tecnico" name="radio">
    <label for="cc_auxiliar">Cambiar cédula instalador y auxiliar</label>
    <input type="radio" id="cc_auxiliar" name="radio">


    <input type="text" placeholder="Número de consumo">
    <input type="text" id="caja_tec" style="display:none" placeholder="Cédula técnico">
    <input type="text" id="caja_aux" style="display:none" placeholder="Cédula auxiliar">

</div>
```

Aquí el código del script:

```
<script>
var options = {

    url: "/perfiles/facturacion/complementos/easyautocomplete.php",

    getValue: "name",

    list: {
        match: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
};


$("#caja_tec").easyAutocomplete(options);
</script>
```

Y este era el archivo que recibía para hacer el llamado y llenado del autocompletado:

```
function connectDB(){



  $conexion = mysqli_connect("x", "x", "x", "x");
if($conexion){
    echo 'La conexión de la base de datos se ha hecho satisfactoriamente';
}else{
    echo 'Ha sucedido un error inesperado en la conexión de la base de datos';
}   
return $conexion;

}

function disconnectDB($conexion){

$close = mysqli_close($conexion);

if($close){
    echo 'La desconexión de la base de datos se ha hecho satisfactoriamente';
}else{
    echo 'Ha sucedido un error inesperado en la desconexión de la base de datos';
}   

return $close;
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_personal WHERE AREA = 'INSTALADOR'";

function getArraySQL($sql){
//Creamos la conexión con la función anterior
$conexion = connectDB();

//generamos la consulta

mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); //formato de datos utf8

if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die(); //si la conexión cancelar programa

$rawdata = array(); //creamos un array

//guardamos en un array multidimensional todos los datos de la consulta
$i=0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rawdata[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}

disconnectDB($conexion); //desconectamos la base de datos

return $rawdata; //devolvemos el array
}
$myArray = getArraySQL($sql);
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

Al ejecutar y compilar todo esto, en la consola del navegador me sale lo siguiente:

> WARNING:Fail to load response data

Estoy empezando a manejar esta herramienta y plug-in...
Espero que me puedan colaborar... Gracias!

Comment: No conozco ese plugin, pero sí estoy seguro de cuando haces una petición que espera como respuesta un cierto tipo de datos y tú imprimes otros datos que no tienen nada que ver, los resultados no son los esperados. Por ejemplo esto: `echo 'La conexión de la base de datos se ha hecho satisfactoriamente';` está fastidiando todo el proceso... así de fácil. No saques por pantalla ninguna otra cosa, sólo lo que el plugin espera. Si sigues [lo explicado aquí](http://www.techotut.com/autocomplete-textbox-using-jquery-php-and-mysql/) de manera estricta, creo que podrás llegar a una solución.

Comment: He solucionado esto gracias a tu respuesta, muchas gracias!